# Were Devaki and Yashoda avatar of some deity?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna

Devaki and Yashoda were two mothers of Krishna. Devaki being his biological mother . Yashoda , foster mother.

I want to know if any or both of them were avatar of some deity or were they normal women ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Brahma Vaivarta Purana.
Sri Radha-Krsna-samvada. (A Conversation of Sri Radha and Sri Krsna).
Chapter 6.:**

> *182. Candra will partially incarnate as Abhimanyu. Vasu will partially incarnate as Bhisma. Kasyapa will partially incarnate as Vasudeva. **Aditi will partially incarnate as Devaki.***
>
> *183. Vasu will partially incarnate as Nanda-gopa. **Vasu’s wife will partially incarnate as Yasoda.** Laksmi will partially incarnate as Draupadi, who was born from a yajna pond."*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..